# NATS Client throws NATSConnectionException timeout

Tags: c#, .net, nats.io

I'm trying to connect to NATS that uses docker compose.`CreateConnection` throws a `NATSConnectionException: timeout` exception.

By the way, I took the docker compose from the official [documentation](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats_docker#creating-a-nats-cluster-with-docker-compose).

How do I fix it?

```cs
try
{
    _connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection("nats://nats:4222");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  consul-server:
    image: hashicorp/consul:1.13.1
    container_name: consul-server
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./consul/server.json:/consul/config/server.json:ro
    networks:
      - hashicorp
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600/tcp"
      - "8600:8600/udp"
    command: "agent -bootstrap-expect=1"

  nats:
    image: nats
    ports:
      - "8222:8222"
    command: "--cluster_name NATS --cluster nats://0.0.0.0:6222 --http_port 8222 "
    networks:
      - nats

  nats-1:
    image: nats
    command: "--cluster_name NATS --cluster nats://0.0.0.0:6222 --routes=nats://ruser:T0pS3cr3t@nats:6222"
    networks:
      - nats
    depends_on:
      - nats

  nats-2:
    image: nats
    command: "--cluster_name NATS --cluster nats://0.0.0.0:6222 --routes=nats://ruser:T0pS3cr3t@nats:6222"
    networks:
      - nats
    depends_on:
      - nats

networks:
  hashicorp:
    driver: bridge
  nats:
    name: nats
```

### Edit

I fixed it by using the following docker compose and changing the NATS url to `nats://localhost:14222`. Mind telling me what was wrong with the previous one because I literally took it from the docs.

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  consul-server:
    image: hashicorp/consul:1.13.1
    container_name: consul-server
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./consul/server.json:/consul/config/server.json:ro
    networks:
      - hashicorp
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600/tcp"
      - "8600:8600/udp"
    command: "agent -bootstrap-expect=1"

  nats-1:
    command:
      - "--debug"
      - "--cluster"
      - "nats://0.0.0.0:6222"
      - "--http_port"
      - "8222"
      - "--port"
      - "4222"
    image: "nats:2.1.4"
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "14222:4222"
      - "18222:8222"
  nats-2:
    command:
      - "--debug"
      - "--cluster"
      - "nats://0.0.0.0:6222"
      - "--http_port"
      - "8222"
      - "--port"
      - "4222"
      - "--routes"
      - "nats://nats-1:6222"
    image: "nats:2.1.4"
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "24222:4222"
      - "28222:8222"
  nats-3:
    command:
      - "--debug"
      - "--cluster"
      - "nats://0.0.0.0:6222"
      - "--http_port"
      - "8222"
      - "--port"
      - "4222"
      - "--routes"
      - "nats://nats-1:6222"
    image: "nats:2.1.4"
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "34222:4222"
      - "38222:8222"

networks:
  hashicorp:
    driver: bridge
  main:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.255.0/24
      driver: default
```

Comment: Provided more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our case we found that the problem is with **multiple connection requests** happening simultaneously to the server due to parallelism in our software, it means that we had different components trying to create a connection to server at the same time, although we didn't find in [nats document site](https://docs.nats.io/) the exact number of connection requests that the server can handle in the default timeout frame ( 2 seconds ) we created a test that shows the 15 connection requests in parallel will cause the `NATSConnectionException: timeout` exception.
So for that we had 2 solutions:

1. Increase the the time out:

   ```
   var defaultOptions = ConnectionFactory.GetDefaultOptions();
   defaultOptions.Timeout = 20000;  
   connection = 
   new ConnectionFactory().CreateEncodedConnection(defaultOptions);
   ```
2. Wrap the creation of connections with a components that managed the number of connections that you could do concurrently, something like this:

   ```
   public class NatsConnectionManager
   {

       private readonly SemaphoreSlim _serviceLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 5); // number of connections concurrently

      private async Task<IEncodedConnection> CreateNatsConnection()
      {
          try
          {
              await _serviceLock.WaitAsync();
              IEncodedConnection connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateEncodedConnection();

              return connection;
          }
          finally
          {
              _serviceLock.Release();
          }
       }
   }
   ```

> **Note that both of the solutions can cause latency in your system due the timeout delay/lock.**